# Move image inside a container by clicking direction button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have one **image inside a container**. My requirement is to move the image inside the container and get its co-ordinates. Previously I used the **draggable function** to achieve that.

But now I want same behavior by using the **arrow keys**. Please help. Thanks.

My previous code

HTML

```
 <div id="claw" name='claw' style="overflow:hidden;width:320px;height:240px;position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
   <img id='machine_image' />
   <img id='pointer' src='images/circle.png' name='image' style="position: absolute; top: 105px; left: 145px;">
  </div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#pointer').draggable({
cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#claw',
    stop: function () {
        var cont = $('#claw').offset();
        var img = $(this).offset();
        x = img.left - cont.left;
        y = img.top - cont.top;
    }
});
```

Comment: Define *dragging*..? Usually it means, moving the mouse after clicking and holding something, which emits various mouse events,  which the libraries like the on you're using relies upon. Looks like that's not what you want. so you might want to explicitly explain what exactly you want.

Comment: Do you mean when you press the arrow keys (←,↑,→,↓), then the image should get moved in that direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not *dragging* - you will need to listen to the `keydown` event and handle moving the image yourself. This is not too hard with jQuery.

You basically need to see if they have pressed an arrow key, check the move won't go outside the container (if that is what you want), then move the image and store the new co-ordinates. Note that if they hold the key down it will repeatedly call the `keydown` event and the image will keep moving.

```js
// store x and y globally so you can use them wherever you need to
var x, y;

$(function() {
    // set how many pixels to move on each press
    var step = 5;
    // cache references to pointer and claw jquery objects
    var thePointer = $('#pointer');
    var theClaw = $('#claw');

    $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
        // get the current position
        // this is already relative to claw so no need to work it out
        var pos = thePointer.position();

        // now check which key was pressed
        switch(e.which)
        {
            case 38: // up
                if(pos.top >= step) {    // check it will not go out the container
                    pos.top -= step;     // update the stored position
                    thePointer.css('top', pos.top + 'px'); // move the image
                }
                break;

            case 40: // down
                if(pos.top <= theClaw.height() - thePointer.height() - step) {
                    pos.top += step;
                    thePointer.css('top', pos.top + 'px');
                }
                break;

            case 37: // left
                if(pos.left >= step) {
                    pos.left -= step;
                    thePointer.css('left', pos.left + 'px');
                }
                break;

            case 39: // right
                if(pos.left <= theClaw.width() - thePointer.width() - step) {
                    pos.left += step;
                    thePointer.css('left', pos.left + 'px');
                }
                break;

            // let other events through such as typing in textboxes.
            default:
                return;
        }
        
        // store the co-ordinates
        x = pos.left;
        y = pos.top;
        console.log(x, y);

        // prevent default event, usually page scrolling
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('keyup', function(e) {

        // now check which key was pressed
        switch(e.which)
        {
            case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40:
                alert("Stopped at " + x + ", " + y);
                break;
        }
    });
})
```

```css
#claw {
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="claw" name='claw' style="overflow:hidden;width:320px;height:240px;position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
   <img id='machine_image' />
    <img id='pointer' src='http://maps.co.gov/aspnet_client/ESRI/WebADF/MarkerSymbols/circle-black-16x16.png' name='image' style="position: absolute; top: 105px; left: 145px;" />
</div>

<input type="text" placeholder="You can still type in me" />
```